# Ajax update doesn't work in event="roweditInit" primefaces?

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I want to call a function in the backing bean on onclick .

```
<p:rowEditor />
```

So, I've used the event roweditinit but I can't update the 
component with the id categoriePanel :

i've checked out the response using firebug but I didn't find my component categoriePanel :

here is the full code :

```
    <p:outputPanel id="achatsTable">
<p:dataTable var="achat" id="achatsT" value="#{demandeachatBean.listeAchats}"
emptyMessage="Pas d'objets d'achats pour cette demande"
editable="true">

<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{demandeachatBean.onEdit}" /> 
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{demandeachatBean.onCancel}" /> 
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#    {demandeachatBean.remplirCategories(achat.categorie.famille.famId)}" 
process="@this" update="categoriePanel" />

<p:column headerText="Type objet d'achats"> 
<p:cellEditor> 
<f:facet name="output"> 
<h:outputText value="#{achat.categorie.famille.famDesignation}" /> 
</f:facet> 
<f:facet name="input"> 
<p:selectOneMenu id="famille" value="#{achat.categorie.famille.famId}" > 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Famille" itemValue="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{demandeachatBean.familles}" />
<p:ajax event="change" update="categoriePanel" listener="#{demandeachatBean.categorieChangeEdit(achat.categorie.famille.famId)}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
</f:facet> 
</p:cellEditor> 
</p:column> 


<p:column headerText="Objet d'achats"> 
<p:cellEditor>
<f:facet name="output"> 
<h:outputText value="#{achat.categorie.catDesignation}" /> 
</f:facet> 
<f:facet name="input">
<p:outputPanel id="categoriePanel"> 
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{achat.categorie.catId}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Catégorie" itemValue="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{demandeachatBean.categories}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
</p:outputPanel> 

</f:facet> 
</p:cellEditor> 
</p:column> 
<p:column headerText="Quantité"> 
<p:cellEditor> 
<f:facet name="output"> 
<h:outputText value="#{achat.quantite}" /> 
</f:facet> 
<f:facet name="input"> 
<p:inputText value="#{achat.quantite}" /> 
</f:facet> 
</p:cellEditor> 
</p:column>



<p:column > 
<p:rowEditor/>
</p:column> 

</p:dataTable>

</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: If you share your full source code (or a snippet showing the error) we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Can you try async="true" after the event listener? I am not sure why you would not see your panel in the response.

Comment: What version of Primefaces ?

Comment: Primefaces version 3.5